# Сортировка по дате в ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, pojo

Имею pojo

```
public class RssDataModel implements Comparable<RssDataModel>{

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    public String mTitle;

    @SerializedName("pub_date")
    @Expose
    public Date mPubDate;

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    public String mDescription;

    @SerializedName("guid")
    @Expose
    public String mGuid;

    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    public String mImage;

    @SerializedName("image_square")
    @Expose
    public String mImageSquare;

    @SerializedName("image_square_large")
    @Expose
    public String mImageSquareLarge;

    @SerializedName("thumbnail")
    @Expose
    public String mThumbnail;

    @SerializedName("thumbnail_large")
    @Expose
    public String mThumbnailLarge;

    public String mStatus;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(RssDataModel o) {
        if (mPubDate == null || o.mPubDate == null)
            return 0;
        return mPubDate.compareTo(o.mPubDate);
    }
}
```

Вызываю `Collections.sort(List)`. Получаю вместо отсортированного списка по дате отсортированный список по `mTitle`. Что не так тут может быть?

Тут  вызываю сортировку (данные с ретрофта)

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<RssDataModel>> call, Response<List<RssDataModel>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            //Работа с бд
            }
            mRssFeed.addAll(response.body());
            Collections.sort(mRssFeed);
        } else {
            mVisibilityProgressBarListener.setVisibaleProgressBar(false);
        }
        if(response.body().size() < 1){
            mVisibilityProgressBarListener.setVisibaleProgressBar(false);
        }
        mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Добавляю в адаптер в onCreate

```
mRssFeed = new ArrayList<>();

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rss_recycler_view);
mRssRecyclerViewAdapter = new RssRecyclerViewAdapter(mRssFeed);
```

Код адаптера

```
public class RssRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RssRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<RssDataModel> mRssFeed;

    public RssRecyclerViewAdapter(List<RssDataModel> listRss){
        mRssFeed = listRss;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.item_rss_recycler_view, parent, false);
        return new RssRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTxtTitle.setText(mRssFeed.get(position).mTitle);
        holder.mTxtDescription.setText(mRssFeed.get(position).mDescription);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRssFeed.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        TextView mTxtTitle;
        TextView mTxtDescription;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTxtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            mTxtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код, в котором происходит сортировка и работа с отсортированным результатом. У меня ArrayList с вашим POJO отсортировался нормально.

Comment: Код добавил выше

Comment: В общем  получилось  отсортировать. Но  сортировку вызвал  в  адаптере в  методе  getItemCount(). Все норм отсортировалось  только в обратном  порядке, но это я тоже  поправил  поменяв  местами  объекты  в pojo в методе compareTo. Вот теперь интересно узнать мнение  бывалых, на сколько это правильно?